# Observable, async and other

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

After one full day cracking my head trying to find a suitable solution, I'm finally here asking for help.

**WHAT I NEED**
In a service I have to provide a function returning an array of objects; first time these objects are retrieved from a webservice with HttpClient, but then I'd like to store them in a local variable to avoid consuming time and traffic every time I call this service function.
Finally I have to show these objects in a `<select *ngFor` tag and set default value after values are set.

**FIRST ATTEMPT**

**service.ts**

```
  stati = null;

    getStati() {
      if (this.stati) return this.stati;
      return this.http.get<ApiResponse>(this.apiUrl + 'lists/stati')
        .pipe(
          retry(3),
          map(data => {
            if (data.status === 0)
              this.stati = data.response; // <-- this is an array
            return this.stati;
          }
      ));
    }
```

**request.component.ts**

```
this.svcApi.getStati()
  .subscribe((stati) => {
    this.stati = stati;
    this.request.nascita.stato = 'IT';
    this.request.residenza.stato = 'IT';
  });
```

**request.component.html**

```
<select class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="request.nascita.stato" name="stato">
  <option *ngFor="let stato of stati" 
      [value]="stato.codice">{{stato.nome | uppercase}}</option>
</select>
```

This works **ONLY** the first time, but when my router (re)activates the route I get an error in component stating that `svcApi.getStati().subscribe` is not a function; naturally I understand this because this time I don't return an Observable but an array instead!

**SECOND ATTEMPT**
So I tried to change service function:
`if (this.stati) return Observable.from(this.stati);`

But when I come back to the route I get this error in console:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

**THIRD ATTEMPT**
My last attempt was to also change

```
<option *ngFor="let stato of stati | async"
```

but I get this error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null at
>   AsyncPipe.push

I'm pretty sure a simple solution should exist, but being a novice I can't think of it.

Comment: Instead of `if (this.stati) return Observable.from(this.stati)` try: `if (this.stati) return Observable.of(this.stati)`

Comment: @arturgrzesiak you're my life saver :) It works and I feel so dumb. Thank you so much! Please post your comment as solution and I will accept it!

Comment: Why are you trying to manually store the response though? You can do this much easier using basic observable functions. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html

Comment: @appl3r please mind that `getStati` returns a new stream each time it is called and the stream starts with a promise - in this case `.shareReplay(1)` and `.toPromise()` will be pretty equivalent. So `shareReplay` will not help much without further adjustments to the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment:

> Instead of if (this.stati) return Observable.from(this.stati) try: if (this.stati) return Observable.of(this.stati)

Feels bit short for an actual answer, so will give bit more context:

`of(x)` is equivalent to `from([x])`.

`of` basically wraps anything passed to without any modification - `of(of)` is dummy but totally fine. `from` on the other hand assumes that the value is of type `ObservableInput<T> = SubscribableOrPromise<T> | ArrayLike<T> | Iterable<T>;` and will try to transform the original wrapper to an observable. E.g. `from(42)` is incorrect, but `from('42')` is - the latter emits `4`, `2` and `completes`. `string` is indeed `ArrayLike`, which may be quite confusing in case someone thinks `from` behaves as `of`. `from` seems bit overloaded - I personally never use `SubscribableOrPromise<T>`.

Intuitively `from` could be easily interpreted as equivalent to `of`. Imho there should be a function like `fromArray` - especially as there is `fromPromise` which is hardly useful as not lazy. In my usage pretty always an array is passed to `from` anyway.

**Some additional feedback**

In clean state if `getStati` called multiple times there will be multiple requests to the server and the cache never expires.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now I understand it better! What do you mean with 'In clean state if getStati called multiple times there will be multiple requests to the server'? With my provided solution, shouldn't only one request to the server used? Next requests should only use internal array...

Comment: The array will be saved but only when the first request succeed. So during this (probably) short interval between first call and first success multiple calls will fire a separate request each.